# gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn() automatically signs in the previous user after signOut()

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-signin, google-api-js-client

When you sign out the currently signed-in user with:

```js
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
```

And then call:

```js
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
```

The previously signed-in user will automatically get signed in again.

How do I instead show the option to sign in with a different Google account? Does `signOut()` not actually sign out the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can force showing the account selection screen by passing the `prompt`  [`SignInOptions`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2signinoptions) option to [`signIn()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleauthsigninoptions):

```js
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn({
    prompt: 'select_account'
});
```

[`signOut()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#sign_out_a_user) signs the user out of your app without signing them out of Google. Therefore, the same user can sign back into your app without a prompt, because they are already signed into Google and because the app still has access to all the previously-accepted scopes.

You could remove the previously-accepted scopes by calling [`disconnect()`](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/disconnect), but then the user will have to accept the same scopes again, which is probably not what you want.